# How do you compare an entire Json file to it's response using restassured?

Tags: java, json, testng, rest-assured

I'm using restassured something I used a few years back. When doing so I had a folder with Json files in my project. I was comparing these to the actual outcome of the API response. What is the best way to go about this. I obviously need my file location in my project and need to compare it to my response. Is there a standard way to do this.

So originally I had this. Just to check the City from the body but I want the whole thing.

```
    @Test
public void GetCity() {

    given().
            when().
            get(city).
            then().
            assertThat().
            body(("city"), equalTo(city));
}
```

But I want to get to something like this below:

```
@Test
public void GetCity() {

    given().
            when().
            get(city).
            then().
            assertThat().
            JsonFile(("/Myjson"), equalTo(response));
}
```

I'm using TestNg currently but I remembered using Cucumber Scenarios which allowed me to test multiple responses in a data table. Question I have is how do I achieve the above?

```
    {
  "id": 25,
  "first_name": "Caryl",
  "last_name": "Ruberry",
  "email": "cruberryo@smugmug.com",
  "ip_address": "222.10.201.47",
  "latitude": 11.8554828,
  "longitude": -86.2183907,
  "city": "Dolores"
}
```

Comment: I usually just compared the schema of a JSON, not the actual content.

Comment: Save both into `POJO` and use `equals()` method

Comment: @Fenio I've read the tutorial I think I get it. What if you have 1000 users in a list. This surely wouldn't be the best thing to do?

Comment: That might be exactly why POJO is a good idea. You would just create `List<UserEntity>` where `UserEntity` is a representation of a single object. Then you can iterate over `List` with `for` loop or `Streams` to make it even more efficient. How else would you do that? 

I personally had a project where I needed to compare multiple JSONs with 18-70 million lines each and I did that with POJO using `parallelStream()` of  StreamAPI.

Comment: @Fenio Thanks, as I'm fairly new and im just kind of practicing, would you be able to provide an example in code?

Comment: Can you show example JSON content? :)

Comment: @Fenio added to the question

Comment: @PeterKirby Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from the question is to get response from an API and compare with JSON file. How do it:

```
 @Test
public void GetCity() {
        Response response = when().
            get(city).
        then().
            extract()
            response();

}
```

First, we extract the `Response` object which contains information like status code or response body. In this case it will be JSON. Before we extract it, let's create a POJO with JSON representation:

```
{
  "id": 25,
  "first_name": "Caryl",
  "last_name": "Ruberry",
  "email": "cruberryo@smugmug.com",
  "ip_address": "222.10.201.47",
  "latitude": 11.8554828,
  "longitude": -86.2183907,
  "city": "Dolores"
}
```

The above JSON can be represented by below class:

```
public class UserEntity {
    public Long id; //id is exact name field in JSON
    @JsonProperty("first_name"); //other approach
    public String firstName;
    public String last_name;
    public String email;
    public String ip_address;
    public Long latitude;
    public Long longitude;
    public String city;
}
```

Now, we can transform the JSON response body into this class like this:

```
 @Test
public void GetCity() {
        Response response = when().
            get(city).
        then().
            extract()
            response();
        UserEntity userEntityResponse = response.jsonPath().getObject("$", UserEntity.class);
}
```

The "$" means root of JSON file (the first object {}). This is how Response is translated into POJO. We can do it in a very similar matter

```
        Response response = when().
            get(city).
        then().
            extract()
            response();
        UserEntity userEntityResponse = response.jsonPath().getObject("$", UserEntity.class);
        UserEntity userEntityFile = JsonPath.from(new File("file path"));
```

Now you can easily compare them like:

```
assertEquals(userEntityFile.id, userEntityResponse.id);
```

You could also override `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods but that might be too much if you're just learning :)

Comment: Disclaimer: I wrote it from memory so it might contain syntax errors.